# Conda install; OSError: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, conda, python-venv

From my virtual environement I tried

```
conda install -c conda-forge findspark -v
```

I got error.
This is my Errror Report

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1074, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 116, in install
    if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 666, in use_only_tar_bz2
    import conda_package_handling.api
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .tarball import CondaTarBZ2 as _CondaTarBZ2, libarchive_enabled
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_package_handling/tarball.py", line 11, in <module>
    import libarchive
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libarchive/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libarchive/entry.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libarchive/ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
    libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is striking here is that

```
conda install libiconv
```

produces exactly the same error. I am sure that this is Ubuntu issue.

More info

```
  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=/home/mm/anaconda3/bin/conda
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/mm/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/mm/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
            DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
                   GOPATH=/home/mm/go
           MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
                     PATH=/home/mm/anaconda3/bin:/home/mm/myenv/bin:/home/mm/.asdf/shims:/home/m
                          m/.asdf/bin:/home/mm/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
                          :/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/
                          bin:/home/mm/go/bin:/bin:/home/mm/go/bin:/opt/spark/bin:/opt/spark/sbi
                          n
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
               WINDOWPATH=2
```

And

```
   active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /home/mm/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/mm/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.15.1
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /home/mm/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/mm/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/mm/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/mm/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/mm/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Linux/4.15.0-62-generic ubuntu/18.04.3 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04. I was looking at similar SO and other forums questions,it seems that I have problem with multiple Python installations. How it comes that myenv does not solve it? How to fix this problem?

Conda list line lxml

```
lxml                      4.2.5            py37hefd8a0e_0
```

.bashrc

```
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/mm/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/mm/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/mm/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/home/mm/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup







ldd /home/mm/anaconda3/lib/libiconv.so
ldd: /home/mm/anaconda3/lib/libiconv.so: No such file or directory
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH gives empty line

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: You should add ***-v*** (verbose) flag and post all the error text.

Comment: @CristiFati The same with -v,take a look.

Comment: Does it behave like that for other packages as well? Not a *conda* expert, but did you try installing the package via *pip*?

Comment: did you try to run `conda activate` (no argument), this kind of error usually happens when your conda is not initialized correctly. What do you have in your `.bashrc`

Comment: @FlyingTeller I posted relevenat .bashrc part.

Comment: It looks like something broke your Conda. Did you recently change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Is `libiconv.so.2` present in `/home/mm/anaconda3/lib`?

Comment: Also, could you post the output from `ldd /home/mm/anaconda3/lib/libiconv.so`?

Comment: Yeah,I messed with LD_LIBRARY_PATH. How to fix this?

Comment: @MikiBelavista what did you do to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?  Can you figure out where libiconv is? You probably need to at least temporarily add it's containing folder back to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Then, once Conda is working (fingers crossed), I'd install libiconv in **base** via Conda, and see if Conda will run after that without the  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` entry.

Comment: BTW, please @ me next time you respond - that way you don't end up waiting days for feedback.